# QGIS: create layout with one map its attribute table per feature

Tags: qgis, print-composer, map-book

In QGIS I am trying to create a survey report with a map atlas so that they are both on single A4 page showing the attribute table per feature (with field headings) with a corresponding map of said one point feature. I have 800 features in the survey. The goal is to create 800 individual PDFs that have a map and attribute table of the individual feature. I can produce the maps but not with the table entry showing the one feature.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Could you edit your question and give a better explanation of what you're trying to do? Do you mean you want to display a single object from a layer, and its corresponding attribute table, with the table showing a single row?

Comment: Sorry I thought it was clear. 800 individual PDFs with each one showing location map and attribute table of the individual feature. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to filter your table with the current atlas feature, for example for a column "fid" it could be:

```
"fid" = attribute( @atlas_feature, 'fid' )
```

[image]

Comment: eurojam thanks for the help greatly appreciated