# Make one page per a specific attribute table feature in layout manager

Tags: layout-manager

I'm a QGIS newbie trying to make things work here. I am working with tree inspections. I gather data with QField to an attribute table which I've created. For example, tree number, tree species, general information, and so on.

Now I would like to use the layout manager to make a report out of the gathered data. What I would like to achieve is that on one page, there would be data and pictures only from one specific tree. On the next page there would be the same from another tree. I do not need a map on each page, because the trees could for example be in a park very close to each other.

My idea is that I would have template to use for future reports. Earlier this has been done in Word or Powerpoint, but if you have 500 trees, that is a lot of copy/paste and the risk for errors is very big. Now I would like to automate this, so as I have already gathered and written the data it would easily be in the form of a report.
In my mind it does not sound like a very difficult thing. You have and item on the page that points to a specific feature in the attribute table. Then shows only the the feature for one tree, not all for example "tree species" in the whole attribute table.

I found this question here:
[QGIS: create layout with one map its attribute table per feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376574/qgis-create-layout-with-one-map-its-attribute-table-per-feature)

But I am not sure if it is the same thing, and even though it would be I did not understand what was meant there.

Could someone point me towards a tutorial or something?

Comment: You should look at the Layout Atlas